# Negating a conditional expression

Tags: bash, conditional-statements

Is this the way to negate an expression, or should I put the negation inside `[[ ]]` ?

```
  if ! [[ -z "$k" ]]; then
    printf '%s\n'  \
      "[[ -z \"\$k\" ]] returns false a test for zero length"
  fi
```

Comment: you can do it either way

Comment: Also, the negation of `-z` is `-n`

Comment: I tried it, but wondered what most people would prefer.  Perhaps how I do it is inefficient?

Comment: Yes, the expression `[[ ! -z "$k" ]]` is valid and it is equivalent to `[[ -n "$k" ]]`.

Comment: It is wrong to state that this question already has answers as indicated, because indicated answer does not mention equivalence with  `[[ ! -z "$k" ]]`.

Comment: @Bennings: I have added an additional answer above and hope this helps you.

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) reports a style issue with both options.  [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) can identify many common problems with shell code.  The report includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.

Comment: In this case, `if [[ -n $k ]]; then` is simpler and clearer than both options.  Some might prefer the even shorter, but equivalent, `if [[ $k ]]; then`